# Unique partialFilterExpression Index on array of objects not working

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with object structure like so:

```
{
    emails: [{email:"bob@jones.com", type: "work"}],
    _companyId: "FLEHFHOIEFHOIHEFHL"
}
```

I want to create a unique index so that the combination of `emails` and `_companyId` is unique.  I would just make a simple compound index, but when I save two people without emails, it throws an error on the second, because it has indexed no value for the `emails.email` field, leaving just the `_companyId` in the index, which throws a duplicate key error when I try to insert the second without email.  I want it only to index the field if there is an email present.  So I found the `partialFilterExpression` capability.  Unfortunately, this isn't working!  It doesn't throw any errors, but it happly allows duplicates!

```
People.ensureIndex({ 'emails.email': 1, _companyId: 1 }, {
    unique: 1,
    partialFilterExpression: {
        "emails": { "email": { $and: [{ $exists: true, $ne: "" }] } }
    },
    collation: { locale: "en", strength: 2 }
});
```

So I changed it to this:

```
People._ensureIndex({ 'emails.email': 1, _companyId: 1 }, {
    unique: 1,
    partialFilterExpression: {
        "emails.email": { $and: [{ $exists: true, $ne: "" }] }
    },
    collation: { locale: "en", strength: 2 }
});
```

And it won't create the index at all saying:

`Error: key emails.email must not contain '.'`

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do, or is it a lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out:

```
People.ensureIndex({ 'emails.email': 1, _companyId: 1 }, {
    unique: 1,
    partialFilterExpression: {
        "emails.email": {  $exists: true }
    },
    collation: { locale: "en", strength: 2 }
});
```

It said that I couldn't use `$ne`, so I just had to make sure in my code to remove any blank values.